# Simpliest way to transform a Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Foo> > to IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo> > in Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, ienumerable

I have an object `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Foo> >` on one side, and a function taking a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo> >` on the other side.

What is the simpliest way to transform from one to the other in Linq, I can't think of something nice, all my tries ended with foreach loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
return dictionary.Values.Select(nested => nested.Values);
```

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: Thanks, fixed - it's now much simpler :)

Comment: @w0lf: No, it wasn't right before - I was trying to go too far. The simpler version works though.

Answer (score 2):

The result from

```
   var list = dict.Values.Select(kv => kv.Values);
```

is assignable to a parameter of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo> >`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var result = dict.Select(d => d.Value.Select(i => i.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var result= (
        from d in dic
        select
            (
                from values in d.Value
                select values.Value
            )
    );
```